# MathJax v3 on Google Colaboratory

Tags: latex, google-colaboratory, mathjax

I want to set up MathJax v3 on Google Colaboratory so as to use [the physics packages][1].
Is it possible?
If so, could you let me know how to set up?

I can use MathJax v3 on blogger in adding the following script inside <head><meta>...</meta></head>.

```
<script src='https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6'/>
<script async='async' id='MathJax-script' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js'/>
<script>
    window.MathJax = {
    loader: {load: ['[tex]/physics']},
    tex: {packages: {'[+]': ['physics']}}
    };
</script>
```

Comment: I followed this link:
http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/physics.html